# How can I do something on touch but not on touch and drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I'm building a responsive site and the main navigation shows the sub-navigation on `hover`. On touch screens it does this on `click` (`touchstart` more specifically).

On desktop when the user is no longer hovering over the nav or sub nav it goes away. To achieve the same kind of thing on touch screen I have bound a function to the `touchstart` event of the `body`. This function checks whether the touch happened on an element within the `nav`. If it didn't it closes an sub-navigation that is open.

The trouble is I only want this to happen if the user taps outside the `nav`, *not* if they scroll. How can I check whether the user scrolled as opposed to just tapping?

The function so far is this:

```
$('body').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('nav').length == 0) {
        closeAll();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd detect where they touched (co-ordinates) on touchstart, and set a time to check a few milliseconds after... if the touch point has moved more than a few pixels, they're scrolling.

EDIT:
Something else I came across when coding for a touchscreen interface is that [certain devices have a built-in delay of ~300ms when using click()](http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone). You can override this, if you haven't already.